# Java openCV embebbed on Web App

Tags: eclipse, maven, spring-mvc, opencv, native

I am using springMVC and Maven
I added as it as a user library
It give bellow error

```
HTTP Status 500 - Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java248 in java.library.path
```

enyone can help me 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the opencv_java248.so from OpenCV lib folder into your Java JVM lib folder to make it available runtime.

First check which JVM you actually use. JAVA_HOME is good starting point. Then copy the .so file into native library folder. The location varies, but in my case that was in:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/
```

Notice the 'jre' part here. There is a lib folder also directly under jdk folder and it does not work from there at runtime.

Since you get this error, you are trying to load the library correctly in Java. Something like this is needed for that:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
}
```

Where `org.opencv.core.Core` is from opencv248.jar.